# How to register whatsapp webhook

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I need to do an integration with twilio where the application serves multiple accounts. With that I have the need to receive the whatsapp integrations in different URL for each user of the application.

I would like to register these URLs in a simple way, without my user having to access the twilio panel.

How can I register a whatsapp WebHook using HTTP APIs or nodejs SDK?

I searched the documentations and even debugged the nodejs SDK and couldn't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What’s integration allows you toconfigure one URL per number. How about setting that URL to your backend which then breaks out the behavior based on the from number.